# Unable to install Py3o Report Engine

Tags: module, odoo, odoo-10

Has anyone tried installing Py3o Report Engine.
https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/report_py3o/

I manage add the module in the apps updated list through developer mode but unbable to install it with the following error:

error:

```
Unable to install module "report_py3o" because an external dependency is not met: No module named py3o.template
```

Then i tried to install py3o.template python library through commandline and got the following result:

pip install py3o.template

Commandline output:

```
 C:\Users\Admin>pip install py3o.template
Requirement already satisfied: py3o.template in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (0.9.12)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from py3o.template) (28.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from py3o.template) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from py3o.template) (4.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: genshi>=0.7 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from py3o.template) (0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjon.utils>0.6 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from py3o.template) (0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from py3o.template) (5.1.0)
```

Anyone has any idea what is wrong since the dependency is already existed.

Comment: If using Linux try apt-get install -f or else reinstall the package after removing it.

Comment: Commandline output don't show any error. But it's from python3. Odoo 10 run under Python 2. you need to install the library with Python2.

Answer (score 0):

Check list installed:

```
pip list
```

Try uninstalling

```
pip uninstall your_package
```

And reinstall

```
pip install your_package
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/py3o.template/#files --> uncompress and run: python setup.py install

Comment: Still the same after your suggestion.Unable to install module "report_py3o" because an external dependency is not met: No module named py3o.template,Could it be looking for a specific version?

Answer (score 0):

Installed the dependencies like this:

```
pip install py3o.template
pip install py3o.formats
```